# Regex search in list for numbers have 3 or more digit occures

Tags: regex

I have list of 6 digits number from [0-9].

Examples:

```
001601
001602
001610
145784
487457
894571
111299
121118
```

Results:

```
001601
001602
001610 zero occurs 3 times
111299 one occurs 3 times 
121118 one occurs 4 times
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Please also share your attempts.

Comment: This is not a job for regex

Comment: You seem to be missing what you tried, what you want, what your problem was, and what your research attempts were.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl way to do it:

```
my $re = qr~(.).*\1.*\1~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say $_ =~ $re ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_";
}

__DATA__
001601
001602
001610
145784
487457
894571
111299
121118
```

**Output:**

```
OK : 001601
OK : 001602
OK : 001610
KO : 145784
KO : 487457
KO : 894571
OK : 111299
OK : 121118
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an attemp with php --> 
See [Demo](http://www.tehplayground.com/#heDinRI1J)

**Code :**

```
$tada = array("001601", "001602", "001610", "145784", 
           "487457", "894571", "111299", "121118"); 

foreach($tada as $row)
{

$nb_occur_str = 0;
$value_occur = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
{
    //echo $i . " is present " . substr_count($row, $i) . "times\n";
    if($nb_occur_str < substr_count($row, $i))
    {
        $nb_occur_str = substr_count($row, $i);
        $value_occur = $i;
    }
}
echo "In \"" . $row . "\" " . $value_occur . " occurs " . $nb_occur_str . " times\n";  
}
```

**Output :**

```
In "001601" 0 occurs 3 times
In "001602" 0 occurs 3 times
In "001610" 0 occurs 3 times
In "145784" 4 occurs 2 times
In "487457" 4 occurs 2 times
In "894571" 1 occurs 1 times
In "111299" 1 occurs 3 times
In "121118" 1 occurs 4 times
```